# jQuery $('.div').each only running one iteration

Tags: jquery, html, css

EDIT : For anyone who cares, the problem was so simple that I overlooked it, since I was using a table if the column on the right was the column with the extra content it would try to change the one on the left as it would still have a greater height, although reducing the text size would not actually fix it thus causing the loop I was getting, the solution was to use independent divs instead! Hope this helps someone!

I'm having a slight issue with some jQuery that I'm trying to write. What I want to do is go through every div with the same class, if that div is has a height greater then 25px then to decrease the font size by 1px until it fits on to one line.

The code I have works for the first one, but doesn't run on the other divs, any help would be great!

Regards,

Shikoki

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.lmmteam').each(function() {
            $('.lmmteam').css('font-size', '30px');
                while( $('.lmmteam').height() > 25 ) 
                    {
                        $('.lmmteam').css('font-size', (parseInt($('.lmmteam').css('font-size')) - 1) + "px" );
                    }
            });
    });
```

Just thought I should add the html markup as well to make it easier here you go!

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="randomclass"></td>
    <td class="lmmteam">Long text</td>
    <td class="randomclass"></td>
    <td class="randomclass"></td>
    <td class="lmmteam">Long text</td>
    <td class="randomclass"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="randomclass"></td>
    <td class="lmmteam">Long text</td>
    <td class="randomclass"></td>
    <td class="randomclass"></td>
    <td class="lmmteam">Long text</td>
    <td class="randomclass"></td>
  </tr>
```

And there are several rows but the format remains the same. Thanks!

Comment: Your code is working fine for me. See: http://jsfiddle.net/QYfbY/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.lmmteam').each(function() {
        $(this).css('font-size', '30px');
        while ($(this).height() > 25) {
            $(this).css('font-size', (parseInt($(this).css('font-size'),10) - 1) + "px");
        }
    });
});​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ta5Jb/1)**

Comment: When I use this the page goes in to an infinite loop, I tried something like that before but kept getting the same issue (same as MJB who posted :'( )

Comment: No infinite loop here at all unless your code is different from what you posted. Check the fiddle.

Comment: I'm still getting the loop on the actual site, do you mind if I PM you the details?

Comment: Sorry, there aren't any PM's on SO.

Comment: ^_^ Well you learn something new everyday, I've just made a quick jsFiddle and it isn't working on here, this is an exact snipped of the code from my site I changed some dimensions to make it easier to see on here. http://jsfiddle.net/U2vLh/2/

Comment: I think you're setting an unrealistic height in your check. For example, if you check it against `$(this).height() > 40` it works fine. See http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/U2vLh/4/

Comment: Okay I've tinkered around with it on the website and I've made "some" progress, I've got it going through each iteration but it is currently setting them all to the size of the last iteration. 


$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.lmmteam').css('font-size', '130px');
   $('.lmmteam').each(function() {
    while( $(this).height() > 25 ) 
     {
      $('.lmmteam').css('font-size', (parseInt($('.lmmteam').css('font-size')) - 1) + "px" );
     }
   });
  });


I know this is because I'm no longer using $(this) duing the while, but this has stopped it from looping on the site, any idea why?

Comment: Sounds like not using `$(this)` would cause it.

Comment: But when I use $(this) the page stops loading, I've decided the problem is within the while loop, but I can't quite work out why it wont let me use $(this) in there

Comment: Could be other code conflicting. Might want to post a link to your page with the issue.

Comment: I would but it's a big project with a NDA etc, I've got an idea of a way around it but in all honesty it should have worked this way. I'll just give each div a unique id when it is created and add them to an array and use a counter with .each, should be fine. Thanks for all your help though!

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `$(this)` for iteration.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/4St7V/1/

Answer (score 2):

You have to iterate thrue the same element and you can use `"-=1"` instead.

```
$('.lmmteam').each(function() {
    $element = $(this);
    $element.css('font-size', '30px');
    while( $element.height() > 25 ) {
        $element.css('font-size', "-=1");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `.each(function()` maybe you should use `$(this)` to iterate over the items.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.lmmteam').each(function() {
            $(this).css('font-size', '30px');
                while( $(this).height() > 25 ) 
                    {
                        $(this).css('font-size', (parseInt($(this).css('font-size')) - 1) + "px" );
                    }
            });
    });
```

Comment: When I use this the page goes in to an infinite loop, I tried something like that before but kept getting the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Three liner workaround:

```
$('.lmmteam').css('font-size', '30px').filter(function(){
    return $(this).height() > 25;
}).css('font-size', '-=1px');
```